# Find music tempo with a audio signal

Tags: pattern-recognition

I'd like to know if there is statistical techniques that aims to find the rhythm/tempo of a music based on audio signal :

[image: Audio signal]

Comment: +1  But the example is really funny: the introduction to this symphony is usually played in no fixed tempo!

Comment: I wish my brain could do this!

Comment: Here is a question you might be interested in: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/extracting-audio-track-to-determine-the-song-beat

Answer (score 1):

Autocorrelation is one of the usual ways to find tempo. Anyway, what you are actually interested in is called *music information retrieval*. Start looking around from Wikipedia. Then move on and make searches at http://www.pubmed.org/ (there's a plenty of brain research that consider these issues).

Comment: Thanks for your links. Is there also techniques (like time series) who can learn with an learning step :
- 1/A human press a button on the highlight moment of the song.

- 2/ The model find the highlight moments for others songs based on the audio signal.